# JUnit add Action to existing one

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I have a default action that i want always called when a method is called, like so :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    context = new JUnit4Mockery() {{
        setThreadingPolicy(new Synchroniser());
     }};
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        allowing(mockDispatcher).dispatch(with(any(EntityBase.class)));
        will(doAll(dispatchAction));
    }});
}
```

and then i want to add a action in just one test :

```
@Test
public void getEventMessages_Test() throws Exception {
    allowing(mockDispatcher).dispatch(with(any(EntityBase.class)));
    will(doAll(otherAction));
}
```

But only the firs action is called. If i remove Expectations from set up then otherAction is called.
How can i achieve that both action will be called?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, I am struggling to understand your question. You need to call context.assertIsSatisfied() to actually check your expectations.

Comment: I do that in @After.
The problem is if i have that allowing in setUp, otherAction is never ever called when dispatch method is called. Only dispatchAction. If i comment out the allowing...will(doAll(dispatchAction)) otherAction IS called

Comment: So i don't know if this is a bug, of i don't know how to add new Action after you already define an Action on the same method call.